# How can i get vuejs filter work for nested Items inside the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, multidimensional-array, v-model

In `Vuejs` there is an `input` field which the user can enter text to search for the item.

The code works when it is search normally.
How do i get the filter to work for nested items, so that the user can enter search based on the item value as well ?

Eg : If the user enters Seat the array should be

```
sales:[
  {
        id: 2,
        type: "Bike2",
        number: 3000,
           item: [
          {
            id: 400,
            name: "Seat"
          },
          {
            id: 200,
            name: "Handle"
          }
        ]
      }]
```

[Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/sionafernandes/pen/xxRPGdw)

The html :

```
<div id="container">
  <input type="text" placeholder="enter text" v-model="value">
  <p>{{ value }}</p>
  <div v-for=" sale in filteredList">
    {{sale.type}}
  </div>

  <!--     <div v-for=" sale in filteredNestedList">
      {{sale.type}}
    </div> -->
</div>
```

The filtering :

```
new Vue({
  el: "#container",
  data: {
    value: "",
    sales: [
      {
        id: 1,
        type: "Bike1",
        number: 2000,
        item: [
          {
            id: 100,
            name: "Wheel"
          },
          {
            id: 200,
            name: "Handle"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        type: "Bike2",
        number: 3000,
        item: [
          {
            id: 400,
            name: "Seat"
          },
          {
            id: 200,
            name: "Handle"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
   computed: {
     //Nested
    filteredNestedList() {
      return this.sales.filter((sale) => {
        return sale.item.filter((item)=>{
          return item.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase());
        })
      });
    },
     
     
    //Works for items which are not nested
    filteredList() {
      return this.sales.filter((sale) => {
        return sale.type.toLowerCase().includes(this.value.toLowerCase());
      });
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```js
    filteredNestedList() {
      if (this.value == '') {return this.sales}
      const parents = this.sales.filter((sale) => {
        return sale.type.toLowerCase().includes(this.value.toLowerCase());
      });
      const childs = this.sales.filter((sale) => {
          return sale.item.filter((it) => {
            return it.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.value.toLowerCase())
          }).length;
      });
      console.log(childs)
      return parents.concat(childs)
    },
```

My approach is making a separation for object search. First off we search which parents have match value and store it in a variable.
Then go again with object search for the child `item`. Not so different with the first one, we also filter the parents but the checked value is on its child, so we only need to know whether the child is empty or not. The return of this process is array of filtered `sales` same as first search.

Last step, just merge the array we have got from those two filtering.